# "Undefined offset", where is the mistake? (array, php)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I did a array with some things in it and it works just perfect! now i returned the array to my view (the html) and want to use it in my html.. but it gives me this error message:

```
Undefined offset: 2 (View: /path/data.blade.php)
```

but I can't see why.. in my controller it's all fine.. the array works perfectly and in my returning to the html is no mistake too (at least I can't see one)

```
$ipsWithBytesDates = [];
        foreach ($topTenIp as $val)
        {
            $byte_execResult = shell_exec("grep $val /path/domain.log | awk '{print $10}'");
            $add = array_sum(explode("\n", $byte_execResult));
            $add = $add / 1024 / 1024;
            $add = round($add, 2);

        $date_execResult = shell_exec("grep $val /path/domain.log |  awk '{print $4,$5}'");
        $date_array = explode("\n", $date_execResult);
        $date_array_pop = array_pop($date_array);
        $mylastelement = end($date_array);

        $ipsWithBytesDates[] = [
            'ip' => $val,
            'bytes' => $add,
            'dates' => $mylastelement,
        ];
    }

    uasort($ipsWithBytesDates, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['bytes'] == $b['bytes'])
            return 0;
        elseif ($a['bytes'] < $b['bytes'])
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    });

    uasort($ipsWithBytesDates, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['dates'] == $b['dates'])
            return 0;
        elseif ($a['dates'] < $b['dates'])
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    });
```

I'm returning the variable like this:

```
 return view('/domains/data', [
            'ipsWithBytesDates' => $ipsWithBytesDates,
        ]);
```

and my html looks like this:

```
@foreach($ipsWithBytesDates as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $item['ip'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['bytes'] }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $item['dates'] }}</td>
                        </tr>
@endforeach
```

I really can't find the mistake... I'm stuck, could anybody look over my code and maybe find with me the mistake?

Comment: i updated the question.. the mistake with the 2x shell exec commando next to another was just a mistake of copying it in here :)

Comment: It's laravel? add laravel to tags

Comment: yeah I deleted my comment with the error reporting link. I should've just made an edit ;-) *weirdly huh?*

Comment: okay but the mistake is still another..

Comment: I think that `undefined offset 2` means than your second element (2)  off array is missing

Comment: That's all code you have in data.blade.php? Because it doesn't seems like the error is there.

Comment: You are printing with `@foreach`. Is your `$ipsWithBytesDates` array is multiple?? if `$ipsWithBytesDates` one-dimensional array, then this is your error. Try to pring without  `@foreach`

Comment: of course its not all the code i have.. but i havent changed the rest since a eternal and it was working fine - its just the html part i show you where a problem might be..

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov yes its a multiple :)

Comment: return view('folder.file',compact('ipsWithBytesDates'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return view('/domains/data', [
            'ipsWithBytesDates' => $ipsWithBytesDates,
        ]);`

Should be

`return view('/domains/data', [
            'ipsWithBytesDates' => $ipsWithBytesDates
        ]);`

If this won't work, please paste `dd($ipsWithBytesDates)` before the return view and check what the structure is of your array you are passing to the view.

Based on that structure you could get the right (key => values) of the array.